# Database wildcards in PostgreSQL for specific user

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a user in PostgreSQL that is allowed to create databases with a specific format. I've the following commands to create the user and grant the permissions:

```sql
CREATE ROLE someuser PASSWORD 'SomePassW0rd' NOSUPERUSER CREATEDB INHERIT LOGIN;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE 'hello_%'.* TO someuser;
```

The idea is that the user is allowed to create databases like "hello_world", "hello_something" and so on. So all must have the "hello_" prefix. But unfortunately it throws the following error:

`ERROR: pq: syntax error at or near "'hello_%'"`

Does anyone know what's the correct syntax for this behvaior is or if this is even possible?

Comment: Not possible. However, you could create a function in the default database "postgres" that does all this for you and does apply the rules you want to implement

Comment: @FrankHeikens `CREATE DATABASE` cannot be used in a function.

Comment: Try an event trigger.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe dblink solves this issue and makes it possible to create a new database from a function.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Complicated, but true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `GRANT` manual for `PostgreSQL`, I think it is not possible to do what you want directly from SQL.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html

I would suggest to doing a program that the user can use that will analyze regex pattern and grant all permissions for that database if the pattern matches.

For example in python:

```py
import re

name = input("Name your DB")

if re.match("hello_[a-z_A-Z0-9]+", name):
    # Execute create DB SQL query from python
    # Execute grant all permissions SQL from python
```